# bash command to remove contents b/w two blocks from file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

How to remove everything from file contained b/w two lines that have a specific word ?

For e.g. -

File:

```
Outstanding ..
dd  
gd
count ...
text2
text1  
text3

Outstanding ..
dd 
gswrff
dddfdd
count
text3
text4
text5
```

The Output should be like this:

```
 text2
 text1
 text3
 text3
 text4
 text5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question isn't very clear. But if you're looking to delete text between 2 specific words then you can use this sed one-liner:

```
sed -i.bak '/Outstanding/,/count/d' file
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
text2
text1  
text3

text3
text4
text5
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to capture only the lines with the word `text` in them:

```
grep text < file
```

or

```
sed -n /text/p < file
```

or

```
awk '/text/ { print }' < file
```